# Safe{Wallet} Web App does not work with Tor Browser or Brave Tor mode since recent update

Tags: gnosis-safe

The Safe{Wallet} Web App, which was under another name up until recently, has up until now (the first breaking version is either v1.11.0 or before within a 2 week time span approximately) worked with Tor Browser. To be specific, I have verified this with both a newer version (updated recently), but also a fixed browser version (not updated since the last successful use of what is now the Safe{Wallet} app) that the application doesn't work any longer.

This also doesn't work with Brave in Tor mode.

The exact issue is that when pressing the any of the `Connect` buttons, either under "My Safe Accounts" or the actual wallet page, the frame which allows a user to select ways to connect (so, Metamask, Frame, Ledger, ...) simply doesn't open, pressing the button doesn't do anything.

NoScript rules and CORS have been also tested and any combination of modifying those doesn't help either, despite the Web Dev Tools console error which logs errors which claim that CORS is the issue. The proper URL https://app.safe.global/welcome, is used.

Web Dev Tools Console Output:

```
[NoScript]:0 Prompt Hook installation https://app.safe.global/welcome log.js:32:13
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://o451253.ingest.sentry.io/api/6769196/envelope/?sentry_key=7e9e331798f047b5b35c2c64ff526fc3&sentry_version=7&sentry_client=sentry.javascript.react%2F7.28.1. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 403.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://safe-client.safe.global/v1/chains. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 403.

Code 620: Error loading chains (Network request failed) _app-2ac3d3dde1cab786.js:274:138115
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://o451253.ingest.sentry.io/api/6769196/envelope/?sentry_key=7e9e331798f047b5b35c2c64ff526fc3&sentry_version=7&sentry_client=sentry.javascript.react%2F7.28.1. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 403.
```

Browser Console Output:

```
Error: TelemetryStopwatch: key "WEBEXT_CONTENT_SCRIPT_INJECTION_MS" was already initialized ExtensionTelemetry.jsm:143:31
Error: TelemetryStopwatch: key "WEBEXT_CONTENT_SCRIPT_INJECTION_MS_BY_ADDONID" was already initialized ExtensionTelemetry.jsm:147:41
Error: TelemetryStopwatch: finishing nonexisting stopwatch. Histogram: "WEBEXT_CONTENT_SCRIPT_INJECTION_MS", key: "" ExtensionTelemetry.jsm:143:31
Error: TelemetryStopwatch: finishing nonexisting stopwatch. Histogram: "WEBEXT_CONTENT_SCRIPT_INJECTION_MS_BY_ADDONID", key: "{[SOME-IDENTIFIER-STYLE-NUMBER]}" ExtensionTelemetry.jsm:147:41
Error: TelemetryStopwatch: finishing nonexisting stopwatch. Histogram: "WEBEXT_CONTENT_SCRIPT_INJECTION_MS", key: "" ExtensionTelemetry.jsm:143:31
Error: TelemetryStopwatch: finishing nonexisting stopwatch. Histogram: "WEBEXT_CONTENT_SCRIPT_INJECTION_MS_BY_ADDONID", key: "{[SOME-IDENTIFIER-STYLE-NUMBER]}" ExtensionTelemetry.jsm:147:41
NS_ERROR_XPC_SECURITY_MANAGER_VETO: ExtensionContent.jsm:398
WebExtension context not found! ExtensionParent.jsm:1171
sendRemoveListener on closed conduit {[SOME-IDENTIFIER-STYLE-NUMBER]}.[SOME NUMBER] ConduitsChild.jsm:112
AbortError: Actor 'Conduits' destroyed before query 'RuntimeMessage' was resolved ConduitsParent.jsm:362
Security Error: Content at moz-nullprincipal:{[SOME-IDENTIFIER-STYLE-NUMBER]} may not load data from blob:moz-extension://[SOME-IDENTIFIER-STYLE-NUMBER]/[SOME-IDENTIFIER-STYLE-NUMBER].
Security Error: Content at moz-nullprincipal:{[SOME-IDENTIFIER-STYLE-NUMBER]} may not load data from blob:moz-extension://[SOME-IDENTIFIER-STYLE-NUMBER]/[SOME-IDENTIFIER-STYLE-NUMBER].
Failed to open input source 'blob:moz-extension://[SOME-IDENTIFIER-STYLE-NUMBER]/[SOME-IDENTIFIER-STYLE-NUMBER]' DevToolsUtils.js:699
Failed to open input source 'blob:moz-extension://[SOME-IDENTIFIER-STYLE-NUMBER]/[SOME-IDENTIFIER-STYLE-NUMBER]' DevToolsUtils.js:699
Unable to find target with innerWindowId:55834574850 watcher.js:186:13
NotFoundError: No such JSWindowActor 'DevToolsFrame'
```